# Cgal::Dynamic_dimension_tag error when trying to build vector of points

Tags: c++, iterator, cgal

I am trying to build a vector of `CGAL::points_d` using an iterator. I keep getting an error message which I don't understand. The error seems to be with the way that I try to pass the two vector iterators to the `CGAL::Points_d` object. I think it might center around the issue of indicating the dimension of the points, for which I used the `Dynamic_Dimension_Tag`, but I can't figure out any more than that. The message is below.

`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<CGAL::Wrap::Point_d<CGAL::Epick_d<CGAL::Dynamic_dimension_tag> > >::vector(std::vector<int>::size_type, std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int> > >)’
     Vector_of_points points(u.size(), w.begin(), next(w.begin()));`

Here is some toy code I was working with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Kernel_d/Point_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Epick_d.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


typedef CGAL::Epick_d< CGAL::Dynamic_dimension_tag > Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_d Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> Vector_of_points;
typedef std::vector<int> dbvec ;

int main() {

    dbvec v ;
    dbvec u ;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> w;

    int size_v = 20;

    for(int i=0; i < size_v; ++i){
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int i=size_v; i-- >0; ){
        u.push_back(i);

    }

    w.push_back(u);
    w.push_back(v);
    w.push_back(u);

    Vector_of_points points;

    for(int i=0; i < size_v; ++i) {
        points.push_back(Point(size_v, w[i].begin(), next(w[i].begin())));
    }

 std::cout << points.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've clipped off the error message too soon. It was just starting to get to the good part!

Comment: Oops. sorry about that. Haha. I have been at this too long today.

Comment: The error message is because there is no vector constructor that matches what you've got. The one [that looks the closest is number 2 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector): "build a `vector` of N elements all set to value Y." What you are feeding it is a count, an `iterator` from a `vector` of a different datatype, and the second element in that different-typed `vector`. It looks like you are trying to build a `vector` of X out of the contents of a `vector` Ys, but I have no answer for you other than read the link and pick a better-fitting  constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It had to do with the way I had the iterator argument set up in the Point() constructor. Here is the updated code. Hopefully this helps anyone who wants to fill CGAL points.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Kernel_d/Point_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Epick_d.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



typedef CGAL::Epick_d< CGAL::Dynamic_dimension_tag > Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_d Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> Vector_of_points;
typedef std::vector<int> dbvec ;

int main() {

    dbvec v ;
    dbvec u ;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> w;

    int size_v = 20;

    for(int i=0; i < size_v; ++i){
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int i=size_v; i-- >0; ){
        u.push_back(i);

    }

    w.push_back(u);
    w.push_back(v);
    w.push_back(u);

    Vector_of_points points;

    for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i ) {
        points.push_back(Point(size_v, w[i].begin(), w[i].end()));
    }
    std::cout << points.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << points[1].dimension() << std::endl;
    std::cout << points[1][1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```